# Retrieve AWS SM secrets and export to container environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, docker, dockerfile, aws-secrets-manager

Can anyone suggest what's the best way to retrieve AWS secrets-manager secrets from Dockerfile and send the secret values to Docker container as environment variables after Docker ran.

The reason behind why I am asking this, I am trying to remove all sensitive password information hard coded in different places of git code repository and move the passwords to AWS secrets-manager.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/s12v/secure-exec is a similar tool, which supports the Secrets Manager (including JSON).

As mentioned above, with ECS there's no need in such tools.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ssm-env](https://github.com/remind101/ssm-env), which populates ENV vars from Parameter Store. There is [an example of using it with Docker](https://github.com/remind101/ssm-env#usage-with-docker).

If you are using ECS, there is [built-in support for this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html).